# Comparing function and numeric value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to write  within a template to compare a numeric value and a function.Both conditions should be true.Following is the way I wrote.This is not given correct output.Please give me the correct way to write this.

```
<xsl:template match="cont[last() - 1]" priority="10">
   <xsl:if test="count(.) ne 2 and functionA(.)">
     <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
```

Thanks..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Value comparision operators (`ne`) was new in XPath 2.0, which versions of XPath are supported by your environment?

Comment: Well, inside of you template matching a `cont` element the expression `count(.)` would always evaluate to `1` which is always not equal to `2`. As for the function call, you will need to show the implementation of the function and the input data to allow us to tell what happens. As a wild guess, if the function is supposed to return a boolean value, make sure you use `xsl:sequence` to do that, and not `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: @RolfRander I am working in XPath 2.0.  Here it is used xsl:sequence and btw replacing "ne" with "gt" it works well..

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input XML, and the output you expect? Also, you should show the definition of `functionA`. It would actually help if you showed a complete XSLT stylesheet as it might be the case the template is not actually being matched at all. Thank you!